# iMessage Sticker Extension Rejection Due to "Objectionable Content"

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I submitted an iMessage sticker extension to Apple for review. They rejected the submission with the following explanation:

> Specifically, we continue to find that one or more stickers in the sticker pack contains potentially objectionable content.

Stickers should not offend users, create a negative experience, or violate the law.

I replied back and asked if they could tell me which designs specifically were offensive, however, they stated that they will not provide this information.

My question is where can I find some sort of guidelines about what is and is not permissible? The human interface guidelines provided by Apple for messaging extensions does not seem to outline this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any information you need regarding interface design standards and Apple's policies on content in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines on Apple's website.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/messaging/)

I am curious though, can you link to some of the stickers that you were looking to submit? Curious to see what kinds of content is not able to make it through review, just out of pure curiosity.